# How to retrieve one BlueSky social post using PHP?

Tags: php, at-protocol

How to retrieve one BlueSky social post using PHP?

I found how to POST from PHP to BlueSky Social API as in [Posting to BlueSky social with PHP](https://james.cridland.net/blog/2023/php-posting-to-bluesky/), but I don't know how to GET from BlueSky Social API with PHP.